# Properties of non-trivial automorphism

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I am reading Sanjeev Arora and Barak Boaz. I am stuck at proving the following which the book assumes to be trivial result. Following are the point I am stuck at

> If we are given a graph $G$ ( with $n$ vertices ) then the size of the set $S=\{(H,\pi)\mid H\text{ is isomorphic to G and }\pi \text{  is one of the automorphisms of  } H\}$ is $n!$.

I would really appreciate any hints.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the object you have written down is not a set (in particular, it's not finite). There are *many* graphs isomorphic to a given graph $G$: perhaps $H$ is supposed to have the same vertex set as $G$? [I'm pretty sure that $|S|=|G|!\cdot|\text{Aut }G|$ in that context, though, so we've overshot by a bit...]

Comment: By $A$ is isomorphic to $B$, I mean if there is a permutation of vertices which when applied to $A$ yields $B$. So I guess vertex set is same. Am I missing something ? To a graph $A$ at maximum $n!$ graphs can be isomorphic to it, where $n$ is number of vertices in graph $A$.

Comment: Okay, that's reasonable, and I think the result is true now: My intuitive explanation is that $|S| = \frac{n!}{\text{Aut }G|}\cdot|\text{Aut }G|$. You first permute vertices, but then not all of these give different things, so you mod out by things that are the same. But the amount you modded out by is precisely the amount you're multiplying back in by also keeping track of an automorphism (since automorphisms are precisely permutations which give you back the same thing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the symmetric group $S_n$ acting on the set of all graphs on $n$ fixed vertices, with action the obvious one: relabel the vertices via permutation.

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be the orbit of $G$ under this action.  I claim that the result is just the orbit-stabilizer theorem applied to $\mathcal{O}$.

In fact, $(H,\pi) \in S$ if and only if $\pi(H) = H$, so we can identify $S$ with the disjoint union $\sqcup_{H\in\mathcal{O}} \rm{Stab}(H)$.  Since all the stabilizers are the same size, we get $|S| = |\mathcal{O}|\cdot|\rm{Stab}(G)| = |S_n| = n!$.